# Is there a provider that offers free SSL certificates that don't give a warning in Firefox 4?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority, x509

I am looking to install SSL certificates for frequently used https services. I used to use StartSSL for this, but they "temporarily" stopped offering their services.

I wonder if there are any other providers that offer similar services? I am aware I can self-sign a certificate, but I would like to have no unsafe notifications on all my machines and not have to manually install an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another service you can use is CAcert.org.

They offer free SSL certs, you may want to look at them I use them for some of my certs.

Comment: You still need to add your CA in the browser, this was a requirement. Notes here: http://wiki.cacert.org/BrowserClients

Answer (score 1):

If you can install your self signed CA certificate on all client browsers, you can avoid generating warnings for each site.

Comment: didn't downmod, but I interpreted the OP as not wanting to install any certs, not just individual site certs

Comment: Me too, that's why I started with the "If" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

check out [instantssl](http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-ssl-certificate.html); they seem to have free 30 day certs.

Answer (score 0):

StartSSL offers free certs and are trusted by all browsers. Unfortunately they just got some form of compromise, so closed for business until they sort it out. I've been using them for my blog for almost 2 years now.

Comment: Not an actual answer, he said: "I used to use StartSSL for this, but they "temporarily" stopped offering their services."